# How to call Android Activity on Click of Slider Menu Item

Tags: android

i want call simple Android Activity On click of Slider Menu Item, on place of fragment.
i tried to called activity using fragment but it shows nothing

please help me.

can anyone suggest alternate way rather than this ?

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Log.e("", "In Fragment "+position);
        fragment = new About_us_Activity();

        //startActivity(new Intent(this,Home_Activity.class));

        break;
    case 1:
        //fragment = new About_us_frag();
        Log.e("", "In Fragment "+position);

        break;
    case 2:
        Log.e("", "In Fragment "+position);
        fragment = new About_us_frag1();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {


        Log.e("", "In Fragment");

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all apply *onItemClickListener* to your ***drawer list***.

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            displayView(position);
        }
    });
```

In your DisplayView method:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    switch (position) {

        case 1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);                   
                break;
        case 2:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent1);                   
                break;


        default:break;
    }
}
```

MyActivity1 and MyActivity2 are activities. you can try this method , it worked for me.

Comment: Action Listener Not Working Till Yet

Comment: i have been writen onItem_click listner, and display view method but it shows nothing.

Comment: Stack overflow Not Allowing it

Comment: is there any other way to send complete code  to you ?

Comment: just paste your activity code and related xml file.if you are still facing a problem,  you can follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: give me your email id i will send you complete code, pls....... help me.  i have been followed the same tutorial......

Comment: you upload the code in file hosting and send me a link, otherwise i will send my code you can check with it  .